# openlayers 3 ReferenceError: source is not defined creating routable map using opengeosuite

Tags: geoserver, pgrouting, boundless-suite, openlayers

Hi  I have been following  [this](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-routing/) link to build simple routerble webmaps from geoserver using opengeosuite with ol3 so far it's adding the route if i only input numbers manually  but when i try to drag the vertices it shows ReferenceError: source and target is not defined error in the browser console .anyone with any idea on how to import or include source;
this is the part with error:

```
function getRoute() {
 // set up the source and target vertex numbers to pass as parameters
 var viewParams = [  
'source:'+ source.getId().split('.')[1],
'target:'+target.getId().split('.')[1],
'cost:time'
 ];*
```

this is the full code
                /**
                *@require overrides/override-ext-ajax.js
                */

```
            var geoserverUrl = '/geoserver';
            var center = ol.proj.transform([34.5775181920002, 0.0298810430000458], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
            var zoom = 13;
            var pointerDown = false;
            var currentMarker = null;
            var changed = false;
            var routeLayer;
            var routeSource;
            var travelTime;
            var travelDist;
            var viewParams;
            var source;
            var target;

            // elements in HTML document
            var info = document.getElementById('info');
            var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

            // format a single place name
            function formatPlace(name) {
              if (name == null || name == '') {
                return 'unnamed street';
              } else {
                return name;
              }
            }

            // format the list of place names, which may be single roads or intersections
            function formatPlaces(list) {
              var text;
              if (!list) {
                return formatPlace(null);
              }
              var names = list.split(',');
              if (names.length == 0) {
                return formatPlace(null);
              } else if (names.length == 1) {
                return formatPlace(names[0]);
              } else if (names.length == 2) {
                text = formatPlace(names[0]) + ' and ' + formatPlace(names[1]);
              } else {
                text = ' and ' + formatPlace(names.pop());
                names.forEach(function(name) {
                  text = name + ', ' + text;
                });
              }

              return 'the intersection of ' + text;
            }

            // format times for display
            function formatTime(time) {
              var mins = Math.round(time / 60);
              if (mins == 0) {
                return 'less than a minute';
              } else if (mins == 1) {
                return '1 minute';
              } else {
                return mins + ' minutes';
              }
            }

            // format distances for display
            function formatDist(dist) {
              var units;
             // dist = dist.toPrecision(2);
              if (dist < 1) {
                dist = dist * 1000;
                units = 'm';
              } else {
                units = 'km';
              }

              // make sure distances like 5.0 appear as just 5
              dist = dist.toString().replace(/\.0$/, '');
              return dist + units;
            }

            function createMarker(point, colour) {
              var marker = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(point, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
              });

              marker.setStyle(
                [new ol.style.Style({
                  image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 6,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                      color: 'rgba(' + colour.join(',') + ', 1)'
                    })
                  })
                })]
              );
              marker.on('change', changeHandler);

              return marker;
            }

            var sourceMarker = createMarker([34.5775181920002, 0.0298810430000458], [0, 255, 0]);
            var targetMarker = createMarker([34.624969, 0.050262], [255, 0, 0]);

            // create overlay to display the markers
            var markerOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
              features: [sourceMarker, targetMarker],
            });

            // record when we move one of the source/target markers on the map
            function changeHandler(e) {
              if (pointerDown) {
                changed = true;
                currentMarker = e.target;
              }
            }

            var moveMarker = new ol.interaction.Modify({
              features: markerOverlay.getFeatures(),
              tolerance: 20
            });

            // create overlay to show the popup box
            var popupOverlay = new ol.Overlay({
              element: popup
            });

            // style routes differently when clicked
            var selectSegment = new ol.interaction.Select({
              condition: ol.events.condition.click,
              style: new ol.style.Style({
                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 0, 128, 1)',
                    width: 8
                })
              })
            });

            // set the starting view
            var view = new ol.View({
              center: center,
              zoom: zoom
            });

            // create the map with OSM data
            var map = new ol.Map({
              target: 'map',
              layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                  source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
              ],
              view: view,
              overlays: [popupOverlay, markerOverlay]
            });
            map.addInteraction(moveMarker);
            map.addInteraction(selectSegment);

            // show pop up box when clicking on part of route
            var getFeatureInfo = function(coordinate) {
              var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
              var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
                if (layer == routeLayer) {
                  return feature;
                }
              });

              var text = null;
              if (feature) { 
                text = '<strong>' + formatPlace(feature.get('name')) + '</strong><br/>';
                text += '<p>Distance: <code>' + formatDist(feature.get('distance')) + '</code></p>';
                text += '<p>Estimated travel time: <code>' + formatTime(feature.get('time')) + '</code></p>';
                text = text.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
              }
              return text;
            };

            // display the popup when user clicks on a route segment
            map.on('click', function(evt) {
              var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
              var text = getFeatureInfo(coordinate);
              if (text) {
                popupOverlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                popup.innerHTML = text;
                popup.style.display = 'block';
              }
            });

            // record start of click
            map.on('pointerdown', function(evt) {
              pointerDown = true;
              popup.style.display = 'none';
            });

            // record end of click
            map.on('pointerup', function(evt) {
              pointerDown = false;

              // if we were dragging a marker, recalculate the route
              if (currentMarker) {
                getVertex(currentMarker);
                getRoute();
                currentMarker = null;
             }
            });

            // timer to update the route when dragging
            window.setInterval(function(){
              if (currentMarker && changed) {
                getVertex(currentMarker);
                getRoute();
                changed = false;
              }
            }, 250);

            // WFS to get the closest vertex to a point on the map
            function getVertex(marker) {
              var coordinates = marker.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
              var url = geoserverUrl + '/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&' +
                  'request=GetFeature&typeName=os:near&' +
                  'outputformat=application/json&' +
                  'viewparams=x:' + coordinates[0] + ';y:' + coordinates[1];

              $.ajax({
                 url: url,
                 async: true,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(json) {
                   loadVertex(json, marker == sourceMarker);
                 }
              });
            }

            // load the response to the nearest_vertex layer
            function loadVertex(response, isSource) {
              var geojson = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
              var features = geojson.readFeatures(response);
              if (isSource) {
                if (features.length == 0) {
                  map.removeLayer(routeLayer);
                  source = null;
                  return;
                }
                source = features[0];
              } else {
                if (features.length == 0) {
                  map.removeLayer(routeLayer);
                  target = null;
                  return;
                }
                target = features[0];
              }
            }

            // WFS to get the route using the source/target vertices
            function getRoute() {
               // set up the source and target vertex numbers to pass as parameters
              viewParams = [  
               // 'source:78',
               // 'target:1357',
                'source:'+source.getId().split('.')[1],
                'target:'+ target.getId().split('.')[1],
                'cost:time'
              ];
              var url = geoserverUrl + '/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&' +
                  'request=GetFeature&typeName=os:short&' +
                  'outputformat=application/json&' +
                  '&viewparams=' + viewParams.join(';');


              // create a new source for our layer
              routeSource = new ol.source.ServerVector({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.all,
                loader: function(extent, resolution) {
                  $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: loadRoute,
                    async: false
                  });
                },
              });

              // remove the previous layer and create a new one
              map.removeLayer(routeLayer);
              routeLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: routeSource,
                style: new ol.style.Style({
                  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
                    width: 8
                  })
                })
              });

              // add the new layer to the map
              map.addLayer(routeLayer);
            }

            // handle the response to shortest_path
            var loadRoute = function(response) {
              selectSegment.getFeatures().clear();
              routeSource.clear();
              var features = routeSource.readFeatures(response)
              if (features.length == 0) {
                info.innerHTML = '';
                return;
              }

              routeSource.addFeatures(features);
              var time = 0;
              var dist = 0;
              features.forEach(function(feature) {
                time += feature.get('time');
                dist += feature.get('distance');
              });
              if (!pointerDown) {
                // set the route text
                var text = 'Travelling from <strong>' + formatPlaces(source.get('name')) + '</strong> to <strong>' + formatPlaces(target.get('name')) + '</strong>. ';
                text += 'Total distance ' + formatDist(dist) + '. ';
                text += 'Estimated travel time: ' + formatTime(time) + '.';
                info.innerHTML = text;

                // snap the markers to the exact route source/target
                markerOverlay.getFeatures().clear();
                sourceMarker.setGeometry(source.getGeometry());
                targetMarker.setGeometry(target.getGeometry());
                markerOverlay.getFeatures().push(sourceMarker);
                markerOverlay.getFeatures().push(targetMarker);
              }
            }

            getVertex(sourceMarker);
            getVertex(targetMarker);
            getRoute();
```

Comment: you seem that you didn't define your source, please add how you define it.

Comment: @User2009 thanks but i have tried to figure out how to define the source in openlayers in the function getRoute() but in vain . Am new to GIS. should i use  new ol.source am just confused